# How to Continuously Draw Lines in Pine Script Until Price Condition is Met?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am working on a custom indicator in Pine Script for TradingView. My goal is to continuously draw red lines after exiting a condition until a higher price than the current one is encountered. Similarly, I want to draw blue lines continuously until a lower price is met.

I am considering storing these lines in an array and using a loop to keep drawing them until the specified price condition is met. However, I am unsure how to implement this logic effectively in Pine Script.

Here is my code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("PPete",overlay = true,max_bars_back = 5000,max_lines_count= 500, max_labels_count= 500)
atrLen = input.int(14, title="ATR Length")
emaLen = input.int(14, title="EMA Length")
ema2Len = input.int(34, title="EMA2 Length")
diff = input.float(0.1, title="diff ATR and EMA",maxval = 1)
con = input.int(5,title = 'แท่งต้อเนื่อง')
atr = ta.ema(ta.tr,atrLen)
atr_ema = (ta.ema(ta.ema(ta.tr,atrLen),emaLen))

var int bar = 0
var int bar2 = 0
var int count1 = 0
var int count2 = 0

if close<ta.ema(close,ema2Len)
    bar := bar_index
count1 := bar_index - bar + 1

if close>ta.ema(close,ema2Len)
    bar2 := bar_index
count2 := bar_index - bar2 + 1

green = if atr>atr_ema+(atr_ema*diff) and count1 > con and close > ta.ema(close,ema2Len)
    color.new(#23ff2b, 85)

bgcolor(green)

red = if atr>atr_ema+(atr_ema*diff) and count2 > con and close < ta.ema(close,ema2Len)
    color.new(#ff2335, 85)

bgcolor(red)

var int startred = 0
var int startgreen = 0

if atr>atr_ema+(atr_ema*diff) and count2 > con and close < ta.ema(close,ema2Len) and startred == 0
    startred := 1
    startgreen := 0 

if atr>atr_ema+(atr_ema*diff) and count1 > con and close > ta.ema(close,ema2Len) and startgreen == 0
    startred := 0
    startgreen := 1

var float first_high = na
var line l = na

var float first_low = na
var line l2 = na

var resistance = array.new_line()

if startred == 0
    first_high := high  
    if first_high < high
        first_high := high  
    l := line.new(bar_index, first_high, bar_index, first_high, color=color.red)
else
    if first_high < high
        first_high := high  
    else
        line.set_x2(l, bar_index+1)
        line.set_y1(l, first_high)  
        line.set_y2(l, first_high)

if startgreen == 0
    first_low := low  
    if first_low > low
        first_low := low  
    l2 := line.new(bar_index, first_low, bar_index, first_low, color=color.blue)    // Get new line id
else
    if first_low > low
        first_low := low  
    else
        line.set_x2(l2, bar_index+1)   // Update x2 position of the line (move it to the right)
        line.set_y1(l2, first_low)  
        line.set_y2(l2, first_low)
```

[image]

Any examples or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two conditions basically.

1. When to create the drawing
2. When to update the drwaing

Below code is a quick example for you. It will draw the open price of the given session and extend the line while in the session.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

in_sess = input.session("1300-1700", "Session")

var line my_line = na

in_session = bool(time(timeframe.period, in_sess))  // Update condition
is_new_session = not in_session[1] and in_session   // New line condition

if (is_new_session)
    my_line := line.new(bar_index, open, bar_index + 1, open)
else if (in_session)
    line.set_x2(my_line, bar_index)
```

[image]